# Payment schedule simulation in Pandas

Tags: python, pandas, date

I'm trying to make a payment schedule based on Start Date and End Date but I'm stucking.

Below is my sample code:

```
import pandas as pd
from datetime import datetime as dt
import numpy as np
from dateutil.relativedelta import relativedelta
from tqdm import tqdm
tqdm.pandas()

df = pd.DataFrame({
    'REF_NO': ['VN1211001'],
    'From': ['2022-3-31'],
    'To': ['2024-4-12'],
    'Frequency':[6],
    'Amount':[600000]})
df['From'] = pd.to_datetime(df['From'])
df['To'] = pd.to_datetime(df['To'])

df['Date Diff'] = (df['To'] - df['From']).dt.days
df['Month Diff'] = ((df['To'] - df['From'])/np.timedelta64(1,'M'))
df['Repayment Times'] = np.ceil(df['Month Diff']/df['Frequency'])
df['Repayment Amount'] = df['Amount']/df['Repayment Times']

def add_months(start_date,delta_period):
    end_date = start_date + relativedelta(months=delta_period)
    return end_date

df['Next Payment'] = df.progress_apply(lambda row: add_months(row['From'],row['Frequency']),axis=1)
```

This is what I get:
[image]

What I want is all of the next payment will be showed. Ex: `2023-03-31`,`2023-09-30`...

[image]

Is there any way to make this or sample same with it that I can learn?

Thank you.

Comment: So, do you want you next payment column to contain a list of dates, and not a date?

Comment: @Nephanth: I want list of dates. Maybe rows same with my output and just change Next Payment date (append)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Prepare a new empty data frame and add processing for each row of the data frame. Get a list of start and end dates and payment intervals from the resulting rows. The first start date is not needed, so add rows in a loop process starting with the second payment date.

```
new_df = pd.DataFrame()
for idx, row in df.iterrows():
    pay_list = pd.date_range(row['From'], row['To'], freq=str(row['Frequency'])+'M')
    if row['To'] > pay_list[-1]:
        pay_list = pay_list.append(pd.date_range(row['To'], row['To'], periods=1)) 
        for p in pay_list[1:]:
            row['Next Payment'] = p
            new_df = new_df.append(row.T, ignore_index=True)

  new_df

    REF_NO  From    To  Frequency   Amount  Date Diff   Month Diff  Repayment Times     Repayment Amount    Next Payment
0   VN1211001   2022-03-31  2024-04-12  6.0     600000.0    743.0   24.411179   5.0     120000.0    2022-09-30
1   VN1211001   2022-03-31  2024-04-12  6.0     600000.0    743.0   24.411179   5.0     120000.0    2023-03-31
2   VN1211001   2022-03-31  2024-04-12  6.0     600000.0    743.0   24.411179   5.0     120000.0    2023-09-30
3   VN1211001   2022-03-31  2024-04-12  6.0     600000.0    743.0   24.411179   5.0     120000.0    2024-03-31
4   VN1211001   2022-03-31  2024-04-12  6.0     600000.0    743.0   24.411179   5.0     120000.0    2024-04-12
```

Comment: I'm sorry for not clearing my question. I will need end_date as the last payment and I want something like append new row to show `Next Payment` same with output that I've made.

Comment: Then I can handle it by adding rows in a loop process with the payment date list I created in my code.

Comment: I've tried to use `explode` and Output returned as I want but another issues is that I need `end_date` as the last payment.

I tried:
`pay_list = pd.date_range(start_date, end_date, periods=delta_period) 
    return pay_list.date.tolist()[1:]

df['Next Payment'] = df.apply(lambda row: add_months(row['From'],row['To'],row['Repayment Times']),axis=1)` but the Next Repayment is not exact.

Comment: Logic changed and code updated.

Comment: Thank you for that, sorry but can it include end_date? I used `periods` instead of `freq` but Next Payment is wrong (`2022-08-26`,`2023-01-22`,`2023-06-19`,`2023-11-15,`2024-04-12`).But what I want is (`2022-09-30`,`2023-03-31`,`2023-09-30`,`2024-03-31,`2024-04-12`. Thank.

Comment: There may be a better way to manipulate the time line. Updated code.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/243887/discussion-between-hoa-tran-and-r-beginners).

Comment: Sorry for that but I have another issues that if I use `freq = M` or `MS`,, the Next Payment will be the end or the beginning of month. For Example, my start date is: `2022-04-14`, if use `M` and `frequency = 6`, it will return `2022-10-31`. How can I return `2022-10-14`. Thanks.

Comment: Currently the payment frequency is 6 months, so 'M' is used for term generation. If we continue to consider the correspondence utilizing a payment frequency of 6 months, we multiply by 31 days and set the unit of measure to days as follows. If you want to be more precise you need to add in the time delta to the start date and the logic to account for holidays and public holidays. `freq=str(row['Frequency']*31)+'D'`